# How does the wait function know which thread information to choose from

Tags: process, posix

> The wait() function shall suspend execution of the calling thread
>   until status information for one of the terminated child processes of
>   the calling process is available

Assuming a parent process has many child process , which child process does the [wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html) function choose to obtain the status information from ??? Is it the 1st child process which terminates ???

Does this mean the wait function() will obtain the status information from the 1st child process which terminates and after that the execution of the calling thread will continue though other child process may still be running ??

Can someone suggest for me a better title for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait` blocks execution of the calling program (the parent).  It will process the information from the first child that dies.  That child may have *already* died before `wait` is called, in which case `wait` will return immediately with the child information.  After `wait` returns the program can continue on to do something else, including calling `wait` again - for instance in a loop - to reap any future dead children.

You can also use `waitpid` which allows you to wait on a specific child and has several other options, including NOHANG which allows you to poll for a dead child without blocking and thereby allowing the parent to do something else in the meantime.